# How to get all the attributes of all Products. Magento2

Tags: magento2, product, product-collection

I want to get all the **products** with all **attributes** it tried

```
$productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
$collection = $productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status', array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
);
$collection->setStoreId(1);
echo '<pre>';

foreach ($collection as $productcollection) {
// $productcollection->save();
 print_r($productcollection->getData());

}
```

so If try this then it returns me specific attributes not all the attributes as you can see from the image 
[image] 
but if I remove the comment from the `$productioncollection->save()` as you can see from the above code then it shows all the attributes as shown in the image below 
[image] 
but after getting three(3) products it gives me an **error** 
 [image: t]
how to solve this **error** or how to get products with all **attributes**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your code like below:

```
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status', array('eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    )->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->setStoreId(1);
echo '<pre>';
foreach ($collection as $productcollection) {
    // $productcollection->save();
    print_r($productcollection->getData());
}
```

Let me know it's working OR not?

Comment: Thank U Sir :) it works

Comment: Welcome. 1+ for mark as read.  :)